# Values for List of Pojos inside a PoJo is always null

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Pojo X which contains a List of POJO Y . When i pass the value of PoJo X from Post Man or through angular service..the values for PoJo Y are appearing as null.

```
Class X{
    private String name;
    private List<Y> ypojo;
    //getters and setters
}

Class Y
{
    private String stat;
    private String nu;
    //getters and setters
}
```

In my Spring Request mapping controller method , i am getting the response Body of X.. the values of X are getting passed ..but values of variables of Y like stat and nu are always setting as null value. Please anyone explain as to what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You need to show us the code where you initialise these things. There's nothing wrong with the classes.

Comment: Other than the misspelling of the `class` keyword there's nothing wrong with them.

Comment: I just tried testing using Post Man tool ..by specifying the URL and selecting post method ..and sending the value for X ..in the form of Json .. in my controller when i sysout ..and print the value for X .. i am able to get the value for name ..but when i iterate and try to get value for variables of class Y like stat, and nu ..both are appearing as null..and one more thing which i noticed is when i send ..array of 2 Y objects ..the List Y iterates twice as expected but in both case null value s are coming